# Laravel Error: Trying to get property of non-object when accessing via first() method

Tags: php, laravel-5, error-handling, eloquent

I am using laravel 5.6 with PHP 7.1.

Laravel throws `ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object`  when I try to access property of the post which is retrieved using eloquent `first()` method.

```
$post = Blog::select('id', 'title', 'slug')->where('slug', $slug)->first(); //slug is unique column in database
$post->title; //this line cause the error
```

However, If I use `find()` method, it works without any error.

```
$post = Blog::select('id', 'title', 'slug')->find($primarykey);
$post->title; //No error
```

Since, I can not use the second method, what is the best possible way to access these properties when modal is retrieved by `first()` method?

**Edit:**

When I do `dd($post)` with these 2 methods, I see exact result.
Also the error is getting logged in `laravel.log` file and I can see the page without any problem. This happen only when I use `first()` method.

**Edit 2:**

Here is my exact code:

```
$viewData['resource'] = Resource::select('id', 'resource_category_id', 'name', 'descp', 'seo_title', 'seo_keywords', 'seo_descp', 'dl_type', 'download', 'thumb', 'image', 'dl_count', 'updated_at')->with(['category' => function($q){
        $q->select('id', 'name', 'slug', 'parent_id');
    }])->where('slug', $slug)->first();
$id = $viewData['resource']->id; // this line throw error, line 126
```

`local.ERROR: Trying to get property of non-object {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property of non-object at E:\\websites\\couponclone\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\ResourceController.php:126)`

Comment: Well, guess there's no object with a `slug` of `$slug`? These two queries are definitely not equivalent.

Comment: It is present..
I can see the view without any problem, but I can see these errors in `laravel.log` file

Comment: no matches for slug with value of $slug. you should check the value you are putting as $slug.

Comment: Its matching. I can see the page without any error. The error just getting logged in `laravel.log` file when using `first()` method

Comment: @sanjayojha So you're saying the error states that `$post` is a non-object yet you can see that same post displayed on the page? That's... pretty much impossible :) Are you sure the error refers to that line?

Comment: Yes. The error is only logging in `laravel.log` file.. not throwing in browser. I can see the page and this only happening when I use `first()` method. No such thing with `find()`

Comment: `local.ERROR: Trying to get property of non-object {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property of non-object at E:\\websites\\couponclone\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\ResourceController.php:126)`

Comment: May be I need to loop through `$post` ?

Comment: Can you post the exact, complete line 126 of ResourceController.php?

Comment: Sure, I am using resource.. So below code is little different than above
`$viewData['resource'] = Resource::select('id', 'resource_category_id', 'name', 'descp', 'seo_title', 'seo_keywords', 'seo_descp', 'dl_type', 'download', 'thumb', 'image', 'dl_count', 'updated_at')->with(['category' => function($q){
            $q->select('id', 'name', 'slug', 'parent_id');
        }])->where('slug', $slug)->first();
        $id = $viewData['resource']->id; //line 126`

Comment: @Jeto see my question, I updated it.

Comment: Add `var_dump(gettype($viewData['resource']));` and see what it outputs (edit: saw answer -> no idea what's happening then, makes 0 sense as you can see)

Comment: string(6) "object"

Comment: When  you use where on Eloquent query you need to use `get()` to fetch result. And if you need to get the first element you to use `get()->first()`

Comment: I don't think so: [https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-single-models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

Comment: Hello @Jeto
I found the solution, this is really strange. When I uses `firstOrFail()` it does not throws any error, but when I am using only `first()`. It is logging the error.
I am not sure why this is.... may be due to PHP 7??

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer. This is the strange solution though. When you use Laravel `firstOrFail()` method. The error does not get logged in `laravel.log` file.

So snswer is use `firstOrFail()` instead of `first()`. This will not log `Trying to get property of non-object` error in your laravel log file.

I am not sure why this is so, may be due to PHP 7 or there is a bug in laravel? But it worked.